# userInteractionEnabled is not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

Is not working in `viewDidLoad:`  and  `viewWillAppear:` methods. i.e. I can still use buttons on navigationBar.
Everything was working fine in `iOS 6`.

How can I disable the user interaction on a `UINavigationBar` in iOS 7?

**UPDATE:**

One strange thing I noticed, `self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO` seems working fine with RootviewController's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, but not with other controller in navigation stack.

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO; is working correctly in viewDidLoad:

Answer (score 1):

Using `Xcode 5(5A1314)` with `iOS 7` and this line of code working fine for enable and disable the user interaction with navigation bar.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
// No for Disable and YES for enable.
```

Or you can try the another way like

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
// No for Disable and YES for enable.
```

You can try Empty Caches and Clean All Targets like `Clean` and `Run`. and you can reset the simulator.

Comment: But Working fine on my side there may be some other issue. Can get a downloadable link for your project so that i can help you.

Comment: working fine on RootViewController of navigationController.
Try with some other controller in navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different approach and disable to buttons directly

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Can you verify that you have access to a UINavigationController at all? ```NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController)```

Comment: Yes. I do have access navigationController and navigationBar.
Strange thing is that everything is seems working fine in RootViewController of navigationController.

Comment: How about NSLog(@"self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem"); ?